# An application code to write input values to registers and get the related output from a VHDL driver to an output register

Tags: c, embedded, fpga

```
#include<stdio.h>

//input register addresses
#define C_BASEADDR        0XFFFFFFFF
#define LCDCW1_ADDR       C_BASEADDR + 0x0
#define LCDCW2_ADDR       C_BASEADDR + 0x4

//output register address
#define LCDCWO_ADDR        C_BASEADDR + 0x8

//macros to read and write to and from registers
//register 1
#define READ_LCDCW1()     (*(volatile uint32_t *)LCDCW1_ADDR)
#define WRITE_LCDCW1(val) ((*(volatile uint32_t *)LCDCW1_ADDR) = (val))

//register 2
#define READ_LCDCW2()     (*(volatile uint32_t *)LCDCW2_ADDR)
#define WRITE_LCDCW2(val) ((*(volatile uint32_t *)LCDCW2_ADDR) = (val))

//GP read write
#define READ_LCDCW(addr)     (*(volatile uint32_t *)addr)
#define WRITE_LCDCW(addr,val) ((*(volatile uint32_t *)addr) = (val))

int a=0x1;
int b=0x1;

int main(){

    //input these registers to the adder
    WRITE_LCDCW1(a);

    WRITE_LCDCW2(b);

    //execute hdl code
    FILE *pp;
    //fill in the shell command to execute hdl script insode popen
    pp = popen("ghdl -a hello.vhdl && ghdl -e hello_world && ghdl -r hello_world", "r");
    if (pp != NULL) {
    while (1) {
      char *line;
      char buf[1000];
      line = fgets(buf, sizeof buf, pp);
      if (line == NULL) break;
      if (line[0] == 'd')
       printf("%s", line); /* line includes '\n' */
    }
        pclose(pp);
    }
     //read output from register
    int x = READ_LCDCW(LCDCWO_ADDR);

    //print the output
    printf("The output is : %d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code when compiled using a compiling tool to run on an fpga the following errors popped up:

```
deepal.c: In function 'main':
deepal.c:30: error: expected ')' before 'uint32_t'
deepal.c:30: error: invalid type argument of 'unary *'
deepal.c:32: error: expected ')' before 'uint32_t'
deepal.c:32: error: invalid type argument of 'unary *'
deepal.c:50: error: expected ')' before 'uint32_t'
deepal.c:50: error: invalid type argument of 'unary *'
```

This is how i compiled the C code:

```
/home/mdt/Desktop/Project/tools-4.1.2-mb-ctng-v1.4/microblaze-unknown-  linux-gnu/bin/microblaze-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -static deepal.c -o deepal
```

Please help me to figure out these errors and get it running.

Comment: You are missing `#include<stdint.h>`

Comment: `LCDCW1_ADDR       C_BASEADDR + 0x0` should be `#define LCDCW1_ADDR       (volatile uint32_t)(C_BASEADDR + 0x0)`. The same for others.

Comment: LPs changes and the program compiles, the popen() works. Show us hello.vhdl and why you think you can reach into memory and what's there. What ***get it running*** means  as part of your question isn't apparent.